# Query PIVOT ou SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this select in mysql:

```
  select product_id, presentation, price from variant limit 3;
      +------------+-------------------------+-------+
      | product_id | presentation            | price |
       +------------+-------------------------+-------+
       |       1608 | CCE 1401 / 2092         |     9 |
       |       1604 | 5 Peças = R$ 5,00 cada  |    25 |
         +------------+-------------------------+-------+
```

then I make a SUM :

```
select product_id,   sum(case when presentation =   'Unitário = R$   11,90 ' THEN price END) presentation1,   sum(case when  presentation = '5  Peças = R$ 5,00 cada' THEN price END) presentation2,    sum(case when presentation = 'Bluesky Todas' THEN price END)      presentation3 from variant where product_id = 1604
```

and the result was:

```
           +------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
        | product_id | presentation1 | presentation2 | presentation3 |
        +------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
        |       1604 |          11.9 |            25 |            15 |
        +------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
        1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

My question is,  HOW can I make it dynamic ? without put the presentation name of product ?

Comment: Specify the wanted result as well. (Formatted text here too.)

Comment: any ideas with pivot or sum ?

Comment: You have to use `join` and `limit`,`offset`.

Comment: I'd say fix it in the presentation layer instead.

Comment: what ?  join and limit ?   I don't get it

Comment: any help here ?